# Load data to dropdown using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried to use a custom dropdown to load data to a dropdown using the code mentioned below, and it just worked fine.
But my issue is some time when I refresh dropdown is not loaded after next refresh it comes back.
Help on this would be great Thanks

```
<select class="selectpicker" style='btn-info' ng-model="eventsM" 
      ng-options="color.ename for color in events"></select>
```

Comment: Is it possible to share plunker or fiddle or some relative code of this?

Comment: I used a local db for this data loading is working but when refresh no data then again after refresh data comes back

Comment: $http.get('Services/getAllevents.php').success(function(data){
     $scope.events=data;
     $scope.eventsM = $scope.events[0];
     selectedID=$scope.eventsM.eid;

   });

Comment: I tried with .error(function(err) {
      alert("Error");
    }); as well but error is not called

Comment: I just figure out the problem I was using some 3rd party js from net so loading time is the issue

Comment: Have you checked in browser 'network' section under XHR wheathe request is completing or not?

Comment: Will you please paste your controller code as well ?

Comment: //Calls a service which returns json array of data from local db
$http.get('Services/getAllevents.php').success(function(data){
     $scope.events=data;
     $scope.eventsM = $scope.events[0];
     selectedID=$scope.eventsM.eid;


   }).error(function(err) {
      alert("Error");
    });

   //Using custom bootrap dropdown load data
   <select class="selectpicker" style: 'btn-info' ng-model="eventsM" ng-options="color.ename for color in events" ng-change="updateCombo(eventsM)"> 
    </select>

Comment: Is their any function to check whether the combo is empty and if yes re load data anything like this